# I want to implement a password generator, but so that all options are written to a file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to implement a password generator, but so that all options are written to a file (for example, from the numbers "0123456789" and the password length is 3)
But the file write does not work for me and does not output only with a length of 3

```
function genPassword(){
    var possible = "0123456789".split(''),
    length = 3,
    i = 0,
    j = 0,
    step,
    comb;
    while(i<possible.length){
       step = possible[i];
       i++;
       while(j<possible.length){
        comb  = step + '' + possible.slice(j, j + (length -1)).join('');
        j++;
       return comb;
        
       }
       j=0;
       } 
   }  
 
const m = genPassword();
const fs = require("fs");
fs.writeFile('./text.json', JSON.stringify(m), (err) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: `m` is not a JS data structure. Why stringify it? And your code does work but it outputs the same password every time. Are simply trying to pick 3 random numbers to form the password based on the length?

Comment: 001
012
023
034
045
056
067
078
089
09
101
112
123
134
145
156
167
178
189
19
201
212
223
234
245

Comment: The result of the code

Comment: But these are not all options

Comment: Your code, as written in the question, will only produce `001`. Every time.

Comment: I forgot to replace here in the code return->console.log()

Comment: I can't find an error in the code why it doesn't display all possible length options

Comment: [Are you looking for all permutations of those numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)?

Comment: "*But the file write does not work for me and does not output only with a length of 3*" - please be more specific about the problem. Does `m` have the correct, expected value, and only the file writing does not work? Or does `genPassword()` not return the expected value? Please narrow your question down to one of these and omit the irrelevant other.

Comment: Although I find that it displays all possible variants of 3 digit numbers, I can't find an error here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all possible passwords of a given length created from a given set of characters, you should loop through the array of characters each time picking one and then repeat that operation for each of the picked char till you have the requested number of characters for the password.

```js
function genPassword() {
  var chars = "0123456789".split('');
  var passLen = 3;
  var stack = [""];
  var out = [];
  while (stack.length) {
    var curPass = stack.shift();
    var arr = curPass.length < passLen - 1 ? stack : out;
    for (let idx = 0; idx < chars.length; idx++) {
      arr.push(curPass + chars[idx]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

console.log(genPassword());
```